# Route Not Being Hit In ASP.NET MVC 4 Child Class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why is the first route being skipped for the second?  The first route has the base controller class of the second route, so widgets inherits events, but my events "Registration" method keeps getting hit.

**Url**

```
Widgets/v1/RegistrationWidget?eventid=3762
```

**Route**

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "DefaultWidget",
                "widgets/v{version}/{action}widget",
                new { controller = "Widgets", action = "NotFound", version = 1, slug="event" },
                new { version = @"\d+" }
            );

        routes.MapRouteLowercase(
          "NamedEvent",
          "{Id}/{slug}/{action}",
          new { controller = "Event", action = "Index", slug = "event" },
          new { Id = @"\d+" }
        );
```

**Widget Controller**

```
public partial class WidgetsController : EventController
    {
    public virtual ActionResult RegistrationWidget(int version, int? eventId, string slug, int? divisionTeamId = null, int? divisionId = null)
    {
        return GetRegistration(eventId, divisionId, divisionTeamId, new WidgetRegistrationViewModel(version));
    }
```

**Event Controller**

```
public partial class EventController : SiteController
    {
    public virtual ActionResult Registration(int? id, string slug, int? divisionTeamId = null, int? divisionId = null)
    {
        return GetRegistration(id, divisionTeamId, divisionTeamId, new EventRegistrationViewModel());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your url `Widgets/v1/RegistrationWidget?eventid=3762` action name will be calculated as `Registration`, not `RegistrationWidget` as you expect, so mvc actually use first route but forward it to the base class method.

Comment: I fixed this by having an abstract base class sharing common methods.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put between the curly brackets is what will be used by the route engine to try and find the action you are looking for so since you are requesting RegistrationWidget and your route is set to {action}widget the routing engine will look for an action named Registration in the WidgetsController class.  This has tripped me a up before as well.